# Joomla get Input from Form Field

Tags: php, joomla, module, joomla-module

i have a problem with my joomla module i want to access the value of this field:

```
            <field name="email" type="email"
                    label="JGLOBAL_EMAIL"
                    description="COM_ADMIN_USER_FIELD_EMAIL_DESC"
                    required="true"
                    size="30"
                    class="inputbox"
                    validate="email" />
```

from my php file.
I only saw on the internet big functions for that but does it goes simpler?

Comment: you want to get value from admin option or in front?

Comment: this form ist from the admin option

Comment: $params->get('email') in your module may be type="text" in your field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$params->get('email')` in your module may be `type="text"` in your field